# Limit output values shown within an interval

Tags: matlab, graph

I dont know how to make Matlab show output value within an interval. I know how to fix range for input values (x,y) with `linspace` but not sure how to do the same thing for z. I have tried to define the range of z with function `zlim` but it doesn't work.

```
x = linspace (-1,1);
y = linspace (0,pi/2);
[x,y] = meshgrid (x,y);
zlim ([0 1]);
z = x.^2 *cos(y);
```

I only want values of z ranging from 0 to 1. How can i do that? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Also, you use `zlim` but do not plot anything

Comment: well when i plot the graph the values for z ranges from 18 to 21. The ranges for x and y are perfectly fine

Comment: How do you plot the graph? Please include all code necessary to reproduce your problem. Have you tried `zlim` _after_ the plot?

Comment: ah i run  `mesh (x,y,z)` and did try `zlim ([0 1])`after the plot. I do get the desired intervals for all axes but then the graph is not plotted.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you meant? here zlim crops the image where you choose

```
x = linspace (-1,1);
y = linspace (0,pi/2);
for ii = 1:length(x)
    for jj = 1:length(y)
        z(ii,jj) = x(ii).^2 *cos(y(jj));
    end
end
figure;
mesh(x,y,z)
zlim ([0 1]);
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z')
```

Comment: do you know how to count the number of data points under the function? Like I have already plotted a scatter plot of data points.

Comment: since z dimension is continuous you cannot count points, you may want to compute volume under the surface, lookup dblquad, you have an example in the function itself not too different from your problem